# Identify number of li from group of li onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to identify a `li` element from a group of `li` inside  of `div`

```
<div id="group">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>
```

its quite simple tho, i could give each `li` an unique id and this problem would be over. like

```
var listItem1,2,3 = document.getElementById('liItem1,2,3') etc
listItem1,2,3.addEventListener('click',function);
```

this might be handy when it comes to 1,2 or 3 elements but this is all static and when it start to scale its not possible anymore, Instead im trying to make use of `NodeList`.

```
var nodeList = document.getElementById('group').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

now i will have a `NodeList with li 0, li 1, li 2`
the problem comes now becouse i don´t know how to trace which `li` is being clicked.

```
nodeList.addEventListener('click',function);
```

wont work here becouse it dosent know which one is being clicked at here.

```
nodeList[0].addEventListener('click',function);
```

is the same solution as above. How can i trace which of the `li` is being clicked at? only plain/raw javascript

Comment: You realise that an `<li>` element ***cannot*** be a child of *any* element other than a `<ul>` or `<ol>`?

Comment: lets say it´s a Ul instead, how could i check the number of li element?

Comment: I'm not sure that's really your problem; it *seems*, from reading your question, you want to know which element was clicked, rather than the specific index of that element? As an example, based on that assumption: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f4s5k/).

Comment: Yeah i mean ofcourse to get the number from the li element that is clicked. i have a simple yet effective slideshow running and with the number from the li clicked i can change the current image to the clicked one.

Comment: This is about right, if you posted it as an answer i could credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the index of an element in response to an event, I'd suggest delegating the event-handling to an ancestor (rather than individually binding an event-handler to multiple child-elements):

```
// 'event' is passed in automagically (in non IE browsers, haven't tested IE):
function getIndexFrom(event){
    // event.target is the element upon which the event was triggered:
    var clicked = event.target,
    // finding all the children of the parent of the clicked-element
    // (could use 'this.children', as 'this' will be the 'ul' in this demo):
        children = clicked.parentNode.children;
    // iterating over those child elements:
    for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++){
        // if the clicked element is the current element:
        if (children[i] === clicked){
            console.log('index is: ' + i)
            // we return 'i' as the index:
            return i;
        }
    }
    // this shouldn't happen, assuming we're looking at the right group
    // of elements, but it's there as an in-case and for debugging:
    return false;
}

document.getElementById('group').addEventListener('click', getIndexFrom);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f4s5k/1/).

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`for...` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children).

Comment: this stops working properly if content of any of the `li`s is complex (like: `<li>lorem <span>ipsum</span></li>`) and you click 'inner child'

Comment: Could you post some HTML that represents the structure you're dealing with? That makes it rather easier to provide help.